# create your own swing component

Tags: java, swing, awt, custom-component

A software component is required which allows to find a given word in a given passage, whenever the component find the desired word in the passage the components will invoke all the listener that are attached to it that it has find the desired word.
This component must be used from a Swing UI based application showing user a text field to take a word and a text area for passage. There must be a label which will update its value showing count that how many times the given word has been found within the given passage.

this is my code it's displya gui but count field is not changed or set.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class compomentex implements ActionListener{

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextArea textArea;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                compomentex window = new compomentex();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public interface wordsearcherinterface
{
    public void wordsearch();
}
public class wordsearcher implements wordsearcherinterface
{
    public String word;
    public String paragraph;

    public void addwordsearch(wordsearcherinterface obj)
    {
        obj.wordsearch();
    }

    public void wordsearch()
    {
        //if(event.getSource()==Check)
        String word;
        String Words;
        String [] Words2;
        int disp=0;
         word=textField.getText();

        Words=textArea.getText();
        Words2=Words.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<Words2.length;i++)
        {
            if(Words2[i].equals(word))
            {
                    disp++;


            }
        }

        String show;
        show=disp+""; 
        textField_1.setText(show);
        if(disp==0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Word is not present int Passage");
        }


    }

}

 * Create the application.
public compomentex() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblWord = new JLabel("WORD");
    lblWord.setBounds(29, 81, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblWord);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(121, 78, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPassage = new JLabel("PASSAGE");
    lblPassage.setBounds(29, 143, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassage);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(97, 161, 196, 90);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

    JButton btnCheck = new JButton("CHECK");
    btnCheck.setBounds(326, 213, 98, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCheck);



    JLabel lblSeeker = new JLabel("SEEKER");
    lblSeeker.setBounds(161, 11, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSeeker);

    JLabel lblCount = new JLabel("COUNT");
    lblCount.setBounds(349, 81, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCount);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(325, 106, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of instance variable `textArea` is not initialized.

Comment: Second `ActionListener` is not added on `check` button .

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issues in your code. I have mentioned corrected code below. Please correct.

First - `actionPerformed` method is empty.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    new wordsearcher().wordsearch();
}
```

---

Second - instance variable `textArea` is not initialized.

```
textArea = new JTextArea();
```

---

Third - `ActionListener` is not added on button `btnCheck`

```
btnCheck.addActionListener(this);
```